# Criar carrossel de imagens responsivo no Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-3, carousel

Estou tentando criar um carrossel de imagens com bootstrap e gostaria que fosse responsivo.
Já consegui fazer parte desse carrossel, porém me falta entender a questão do tamanho das imagens.

Segue abaixo meu código:

```
<div id="meuSlider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#meuSlider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#meuSlider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#meuSlider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active"><img src="img/c1.jpg" alt="Slider 1" /></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="img/c2.jpg" alt ="Slide 2" /></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="img/c3.jpg" alt="Slide 3" /></div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#meuSlider" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#meuSlider" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando coloco imagens com altura de 500px o problema é que ocupa boa parte da tela em navegadores com a janela maximizada, mas quando diminuo o tamanho da janela fica com tamanho excelente;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas gostaria de colocar imagens com altura de 200px, só que o problema é quando diminuo o tamanho da janela a altura da imagem fica muito pequena.

Como fazer pra altura da imagem ficar do tamanho que quero em telas menores?

Comment: Seja bem-vindo, Jorge. Sua dúvida está um tanto confusa. Que tal colocar algumas imagens exemplificando o que você tem e o que você gostaria de ter?

Comment: Como citado pelo @Pablo esta um tanto confusa sua pergunta, mas gostaria de saber se você já tentou resolver usando a classe img-responsive do próprio Bootstrap(http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images)? Se esse não for o seria interessante exemplificar o que deseja.

Comment: desculpa se não fui muito claro, coloquei imagens lá pra exemplificar

Answer (score 1):

Defina uma altura mínima para a imagem no CSS.

```
.carousel-inner img {
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Altere diretamente a classe redimensionando os pixel... Provavelmente assim você consiga resolver.

```
@media(max-width:767px) {
        .carousel-inner>.item>a>img, .carousel-inner>.item>img{
            width: 100%;
            height: 240px;
    }

@media(max-width:450px) {
        .carousel-inner>.item>a>img, .carousel-inner>.item>img{
            width: 100%;
            height: 269px;
}

@media(max-width:320px) {
        .carousel-inner>.item>a>img, .carousel-inner>.item>img{
            width: 100%;
            height: 240px;
}
```